# py2app build errors Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'

Tags: python, macos, py2app

I am new to building standalone files using py2app for MacOS. I am getting the following error when I launch the app after the build

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException' reason: '-[__NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000026004e0'**

I would highly appreciate if someone points me how to resolve this issue.

Below is my setup file

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['jarvis_starter.py']
DATA_FILES = ['Template2.pptx']
OPTIONS = {'iconfile':'jarvislogo.icns',
            'argv_emulation': True, 
            'packages': 'certifi',
            'plist': {
               'PyRuntimeLocations':'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/libpython3.7.dylib',
                'LSPrefersPPC':True,
                    }

           }


setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

I am posting error log below

```
Path:                  /Users/USER/Documents/*/jarvis_starter.app/Contents/MacOS/jarvis_starter
Identifier:            org.pythonmac.unspecified.jarvis_starter
Version:               0.0.0 (0.0.0)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           jarvis_starter [64308]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2020-01-26 17:59:07.513 -0800
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.15.2 (19C57)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     3.0 (14Y908)
Anonymous UUID:        0333FAC2-3E0F-7B44-E2C1-9EEFF2508FB0

Sleep/Wake UUID:       E6B1DB47-C4DB-424F-834B-90F142B2FBF5

Time Awake Since Boot: 390000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       700 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000026004e0'
abort() called
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Application Specific Backtrace 1:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2bfd48ab __exceptionPreprocess + 250
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff62245805 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2c053b61 -[NSObject(NSObject) __retain_OA] + 0
3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2bf38adf ___forwarding___ + 1427
4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2bf384b8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
5   jarvis_starter                      0x0000000100001674 py2app_main + 372
6   jarvis_starter                      0x0000000100000f48 main + 344
7   jarvis_starter                      0x0000000100000dc4 start + 52
8   ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff636fa7fa __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff637b7bc1 pthread_kill + 432
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff63681a1c abort + 120
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff6071fbe8 abort_message + 231
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff6071fd9c demangling_terminate_handler() + 262
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff6224778a _objc_terminate() + 96
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff6072cdc7 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 8
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff6072cb6c __cxxabiv1::failed_throw(__cxxabiv1::__cxa_exception*) + 27
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff6071e45d __cxa_throw + 113
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff62245933 objc_exception_throw + 350
10  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2c053b61 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
11  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2bf38adf ___forwarding___ + 1427
12  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2bf384b8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
13  org.pythonmac.unspecified.jarvis_starter    0x0000000100001674 py2app_main + 372
14  org.pythonmac.unspecified.jarvis_starter    0x0000000100000f48 main + 344
15  org.pythonmac.unspecified.jarvis_starter    0x0000000100000dc4 start + 52

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff637b3818 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff637b3818 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff637b3818 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x0000000109351dc0  rcx: 0x00007ffeefbfbfe8  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000000307  rsi: 0x0000000000000006  rbp: 0x00007ffeefbfc010  rsp: 0x00007ffeefbfbfe8
   r8: 0x00007ffeefbfbeb0   r9: 0x00007ffeefbfc080  r10: 0x0000000109351dc0  r11: 0x0000000000000246
  r12: 0x0000000000000307  r13: 0x0000003000000008  r14: 0x0000000000000006  r15: 0x0000000000000016
  rip: 0x00007fff636fa7fa  rfl: 0x0000000000000246  cr2: 0x0000000000000000

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x00000000
Trap Number:     0


Binary Images:
       0x100000000 -        0x100005fff +org.pythonmac.unspecified.jarvis_starter (0.0.0 - 0.0.0) <E4EAF2F4-CF49-3C47-B544-F79C80860A1D> /Users/USER/Documents/*/jarvis_starter.app/Contents/MacOS/jarvis_starter
       0x109288000 -        0x109318cb7  dyld (733.8) <EEA931D0-403E-3BC8-862A-CBA037DE4A74> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff27c7d000 -     0x7fff27c7dfff  com.apple.Accelerate (1.11 - Accelerate 1.11) <EEBE6680-1AAB-3192-AA7C-450537B07F27> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Accelerate
    0x7fff27c95000 -     0x7fff28300fef  com.apple.vImage (8.1 - 524.2) <2BDE5231-B5ED-313E-918A-876ACE1C0FCF> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vImage.framework/Versions/A/vImage
    0x7fff28301000 -     0x7fff2856afff  libBLAS.dylib (1303.60.1) <94F6B3C0-5039-3F66-8B2E-98791287E459> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
    0x7fff2856b000 -     0x7fff2885aff7  libBNNS.dylib (144.40.3) <F15D7D9E-0B9F-34FF-B144-DCA264614C54> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBNNS.dylib
    0x7fff2885c000 -     0x7fff28c01fff  libLAPACK.dylib (1303.60.1) <DCC36295-FF39-35A1-8DF1-1E8A714E2265> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLAPACK.dylib
    0x7fff28c02000 -     0x7fff28c17ff8  libLinearAlgebra.dylib (1303.60.1) <E3C0CC64-906B-3B44-B8AA-3075BA20E161> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLinearAlgebra.dylib
    0x7fff28c18000 -     0x7fff28c1dff3  libQuadrature.dylib (7) <17EC31E3-3D77-3B5A-8ADD-6A3DBC1531E7> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libQuadrature.dylib
    0x7fff28c1e000 -     0x7fff28c8efff  libSparse.dylib (103) <350DAE1C-C990-343F-A98A-1B4317EAA869> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libSparse.dylib
    0x7fff28c8f000 -     0x7fff28ca1fef  libSparseBLAS.dylib (1303.60.1) <8C0C7291-AC3A-3808-9D45-E359A5E03F0E> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libSparseBLAS.dylib
    0x7fff28ca2000 -     0x7fff28e7bffb  libvDSP.dylib (735.40.1) <BD49856D-39CE-397F-A069-
```